# how to refer to an input of a function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function that takes 4-tuple of type list, in the function I need to refer to the input of the function to do some other stuff such as taking the first element of that tuple or get length of the first element of the 4-tuple 
my function takes as following

```
foo (a:_,b:_,c:_,d:_) = do something
```

in the do some thing part i need to do some comparisons but I need the refer to the input of foo and I don't know how .
I went like this

```
let input = (a:_,b:_,c:_,d:_) in foo input // generates error
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4):

You can write

```
foo args@(a:_,b:_,c:_,d:_) = if bar args then (a,c) else (b,d)
```

In the second case you get an error because wildcards cannot appear on the right side of binding expression

Comment: I used it like this but not working `zed args@(a:_,b:_,c:_,d:_) = 
 if ( length ( get1th ( bar args ) ) == 2 ) 
  then get1th ( bar args )
  else get1th ( bar args)`

Comment: Please show your code. I suppose you have a type error since this is syntactically correct